# GNU Linux Debian 11 (should work for Ubuntu too) - compiling latest kernel (Linux/x86 5.17.7) - results in Volume group "name-vg" not found

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

Dear internet & users & robots & AIs & other entities with access to digital,

one fine day... decided to compile the latest currently available kernel under Debian 11.

last time did that it was Debian 9 and with a bit of tinkering it worked.

now of course - things are different - again.

after a bit of even more tinkering, managed to compile the kernel and all modules (i5 took 100Min) https://dwaves.de/2022/05/13/gnu-linux-debian-11-should-also-work-for-ubuntu-compiling-the-latest-kernel-straight-from-kernel-org-linux-x86-5-17-7-work-in-progress-complexity-is-the-enemy-of-good-software-developmen/

problem:

when it comes to:

```
sudo make install
sudo make modules_install
```

it installs...

but after reboot...

it won't find it's previous lvm2 volume group + luks2 encrypted /root

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ...
Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... Volume group "name-vg" not found
```

and then falls to "emergency" initramfs prompt...

imho boot partitions should be at least 1GB by now... because have a few kernels installed and the whole thing blows up, because it is out of disk space.

in initramfs prompt:

lvm vgscan

... nothing... does not find the luks2 encrypted /root partition.

but when booting from usb stick https://dwaves.de/2021/04/11/ideallinux2021-updated-optimized-bootale-gnu-debian-10-9-64bit-non-free-based-usb-stick/

it shows up... ?

(will retry with a 4GB /boot partition and report back X-D)

btw: it was not a problem, getting "back in there" via chroot

and accessing all the data like this: https://dwaves.de/2021/04/11/gnu-linux-debian-10-dead-boot-partition-stuck-at-grub-prompt/

via this: https://dwaves.de/2021/04/11/ideallinux2021-updated-optimized-bootale-gnu-debian-10-9-64bit-non-free-based-usb-stick/

actually when chrooted into the luks2 encrypted /root partition,

tried a re-install latest kernel. and was able to watch initrd.img-5.17-amd64 get bigger, and bigger and bigger...

and finally fill up all of the (per default under many distroy) 512MBytes of /boot

thanks :)

Comment: You probably haven't included the required modules in the initramfs.

Comment: did you consider already [the official wiki FAQ of debian](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelFAQ)?